# How to get the current project directory for an IntelliJ Plugin

Tags: kotlin, intellij-plugin

Is there a way to get the path of the current project directory using the IntelliJ Plugin SDK?

Let's say I create a new project under `~/sampleProject` and open it with IntelliJ. Then I want to create a plugin which displays the current project path `~/sampleProject`.

I tried this

```
File(".").absolutePath
```

which is the path of the `IntelliJ_path/bin` directory, not the current working directory.

Comment: I thought the project Dir was an env. variable for IntelliJ like `${ProjectDir}` (see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/absolute-path-variables.html) but maybe I'm wrong. Additionally, look at their template, maybe there's more information [in there](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-platform-plugin-template). Lastly, [here's a list](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin) of plug-ins and their source, perhaps you can find something interesting in there.

Comment: I checked all environment variables and none of them had the current project directory (without adding it first). By default my IntelliJ installation only had `KOTLIN_BUNDLED` and `MAVEN_REPOSITORY` defined under `Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Path Variables`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

When you create a widget using the `StatusBarWidgetFactory` you have to implement the following method:

```
override fun createWidget(project: Project)
```

Where the `project` object knows the path: `project.basePath`.

Comment: I just realized I missed this from my comment, but I did see the `Project` object and was going to ask you if you had seen any callback where you get the `project`; I obviously didn't, so, good job on finding it :)